# Springboot, hibernate4 and hsql accessing schema incorrectly?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hsqldb

I'm trying to use springboot, hsql and hibernate together to persist and retrieve some fairly boring data. The issue I'm running into is that hibernate seems unable to reference my tables correctly, throwing the following exception:

```
ERROR [main] (SpringApplication.java:826) - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'strangerEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/healz/stranger/config/profiles/GenericSqlConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: user_USER_ID in PUBLIC.STRANGER.PROTECTED_PROPERTIES
at
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
...
```

Initially I was using HSQL's default schema name, PUBLIC, and noticed that the exception getting thrown was that the application couldn't find PUBLIC.PUBLIC.PROTECTED_PROPERTIES. This looks highly suspicious -- why is there an "extra layer" of PUBLIC here? It definitely doesn't look right. The code that does the EntityManagerFactory setup looks like this:

```
@Log4j
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan (basePackages = {"com.healz.stranger.data"})
@EnableJpaRepositories (
  entityManagerFactoryRef="strangerEntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef="txManager",
  basePackages={"com.healz.stranger.data.model"}
)
@EntityScan (basePackages={
    "com.healz.stranger.data.model" 
    })
@Import ( {HsqlConfig.class, DevMySqlConfig.class, ProdMySqlConfig.class} )
public class GenericSqlConfig {

  @Configuration
  @EnableTransactionManagement(order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
  protected static class TransactionManagementConfigurer {
    // ignore annoying bean auto-proxy failure messages
  }

  @Bean
  public static PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() throws Exception {
    return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
    return new HibernateJpaDialect();
  }

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("hibernateProperties") 
  private Properties hibernateProperties;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("dataSource") 
  private DataSource dataSource;


  @Bean (name="strangerEntityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean strangerEntityManagerFactory(
                final @Qualifier("hibernateProperties") Properties props,
                final JpaDialect jpaDialect) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emf.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emf.setPackagesToScan("com.healz.stranger.data");

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
    emf.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);

    emf.setPersistenceUnitName("strangerEntityManagerFactory");

    return emf;
  }

  @Bean (name="sessionFactory")
  public SessionFactory configureSessionFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = emf.getObject().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  /**
   * Helper method to get properties from a path. 
   * @param path
   * @return
   */
  @SneakyThrows (IOException.class)
  public static Properties getHibernatePropertiesList(final String path) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(path); 
    InputStream is = resource.getInputStream();
    props.load( is );
    return props;
  }

  @Bean (name="txManager")
  @Autowired
  public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lcemfb, JpaDialect jpaDialect) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    emf = lcemfb.getObject();

    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    jpaTransactionManager.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
  }
}
```

The HSQL config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@Profile ("hsql")
public class HsqlConfig {
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  public DataSource initDataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                                        .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                                        .addScript("classpath:env/dbcache/hsql-schema.sql")
                                        .addScript("classpath:env/dbcache/hsql-data.sql");
    builder.setName("stranger");
    builder.setScriptEncoding("UTF-8");
    return builder.build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "hibernateProperties")
  public Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate"); // using auto and ignoring the hsql scripts "works", but isn't correct
    props.put("hibernate.default_schema", "stranger");
    props.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext");
    return props;
  }

}
```

The other noticably odd thing about this is that hibernate seems to be looking for a column with the name user_USER_ID instead of USER_ID, and I'm not sure why that's happening either. I doubt this has all been caused by a mapping error since similar code seems to work with a differently configured EntityMappingFactory but I don't want to preclude the possibility. The code for this looks as follows:

```
@Entity (name="properties")
@Table (name="PROTECTED_PROPERTIES")
public class DbProtectedProperties extends AbstractModel<DbProtectedPropertiesId> implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public void setId(DbProtectedPropertiesId id) {
    super.id = id;
  }

  @EmbeddedId
  public DbProtectedPropertiesId getId() {
    if (super.id == null) {
      super.id = new DbProtectedPropertiesId();
    }
    return super.id;
  }

  @Column (name="PROPERTY_VALUE", length=4096, nullable=false)
  public String getPropertyValue() {
    return propertyValue;
  }


  @Setter
  private String propertyValue;

}
```

And the ID class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode ( of={ "user", "propertyName" } )
@ToString
public class DbProtectedPropertiesId implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Setter
  private DbUsers user;

  @Setter
  private String propertyName;

  @ManyToOne (optional=false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (name="USER_ID")
  public DbUsers getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  @Column (name="PROPERTY_NAME", length=2048, nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
  public String getPropertyName() {
    return propertyName;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to not use spring boot? You are trying very hard to work around it... What is even worse is that your configuration is breaking things like transaction management.

Comment: Could you expand on this comment? It's not clear to me what you mean by this. Spring boot does a lot of automatic configuration and it's not quite clear to me what is being performed automatically. I already discovered the hard way that some of these objects were being automatically created and configured. Is a TransactionManager also setup and configured?

Comment: Basically everything you have is auto configured. The only thing that isn't is the `SessionFactory` but why would you need that if you can use the `EntityManager`. I would remove everything create a global `application.properties` and specific `application-<profile>.properties` and start from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume here that you have a `StrangerApplication` in the package `com.healz.stranger` if you don't you really should or move it there as it will save you a lot of configuration.

You are using Spring Boot but your configuration tries very hard not to.

First the application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StrangerApplication {

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(StrangerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean (name="sessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory configureSessionFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBean emf) {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Now create an `application.properties` which contains the default properties and general properties. For the `hsql` profile add an `application-hsql.properties` which contains at least the following (deducted from your configuration classes).

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=stranger
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate # maybe this needs to be in application.properties (?)
```

Then rename your `hsql-data.sql` and `hsql-schema.sql` to `data-gsql.sql` and `schema-hsql.sql` and place it in `src/main/resources` spring boot will detect those for the specific profile (explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) in the reference guide). Make sure that you create the schema and the tables in that new schema in your `schema.sql`.

Everything else will be automagically configured (Spring Data JPA, AspectJ proxying, detection of entities). You can basically remove all the config classes and create the addition `application-{profile}.properties` for the 2 remaining MySQL configuration options.

The general advice would be to work with the framework instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: Thanks! This was a great explanation. Most of the extra beans were being double defined and that caused all kinds of weird behavior. That said, the database configuration I was looking for required just about enough custom behavior that it wasn't really possible to get the asymmetric behavior for a "normal" RDBMS vs an embedded one like H2 or HSQL. I solved that in mostly the way that you're recommending: there are 2 active profiles (one for the environment and one for the db side). The DB side is mostly configured via properties file but there's some scaffolding code too.

Comment: What kind of scaffolding you need to do? generally that can be solved quite easily while still using the auto configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that Spring Boot defines its own instance of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and the second definition was causing strange conflicts. Additionally, there's no reason to apply the JPA dialect in to the `TransactionManager` since the `TransactionManager` will pick up the settings from the `EntityManagerFactory`, which Spring Boot will configure anyway.